# Modulo Pass Through Detection

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, calendar, modulo

I'm currently writing a small time conversion app for a pen and paper RPG game. It's a time travel setting and it uses a custom calendar system. There are the 12 normal months but they all have 30 days except for the 4th (renamed Mapril), which has 60. I'm looking for an algorithm, reference, or anything else that can help with one of the computations. To keep things short I have:

- Current Month [0-11]
- Months to Travel [0-11]
- Direction of Travel [-1 or 1]

So picturing the months as a ring mod 12, I need a way to determine if the current month + months to travel passes 3 when going clockwise, or lands on/passes 3 when going counter clockwise. You can think of the 3 as being twice as large as all the other months. And to clarify, going from the 5th of any month would bring you to the 5th of any other month (including the 60 day month). And going from say the 31st of Mapril would bring you to the 1st of the corresponding month.

Thanks for any help you can give. And if this isn't clear enough I can try to explain better, or provide pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When moving forward, you wish to know if `c` → `c+d` passes through `3`, which is equivalent to:

- `c-3` → `c+d-3` passes through `0`
- `(c+9)%12` → `(c+d+9)%12` passes through `0`
- `(c+9)%12 + d > 12`

For the last step, notice that `(c+9)%12 < 12`, so if adding `d` makes it greater than `12`, it means that it crossed `12` (i.e. `0`) in between.

When moving backward, you want to know if `c` → `c-d` crosses or arrives at `3`:

- `c-3` → `c-d-3` crosses or arrives at `0`
- `(c+9)%12` → `(c-d+9)%12` crosses or arrives at `0`
- `(c+9)%12 - d <= 0`

Again, for the last step, notice `(c+9)%12 < 12`, so subtracting `d` crosses zero only if it goes negative.

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly and really helped me understand the math behind it.